# Why is my MacBook Pro's screen going black for a second?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, display

I have a new MacBook Pro, when I'm using it the screen goes suddenly blank for a second and comes back, it feels like as if someone unplugged my screen and plugged it back immediately.. why does this happen?

Initially I thought it was only happening when I'm running on battery, but happens even when I'm connected too.

This is very sporadic.

Comment: Have you applied the recently released MacBook Pro EFI update (Aug. 26, 2010)? http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1098

Comment: I had the same issue some months ago, but the problem disappeared after a while. Can't remember if there was a software update.

Comment: This is happening again with me, screen goes black for 15-20 seconds, plugged in (sufficiently charged too), seems hacking to me

Answer (score 6):

Clearly, something isn't right. I highly suggest you make an appointment at your nearest Apple Certified repair location or a Genius Bar.

Comment: You'd think that, but it's fairly common I found out : http://bit.ly/awMg9t

Comment: Bummer. In looking at the threads in some of those links, there are pointers to possible issues, like misbehaving connected peripherals, and the like. Either way, I would still take it in to a Genius Bar if I were you, though. At least then an Apple employee can look at it, register the issue into their system, and maybe get you in line sooner for a fix later.

Answer (score 3):

If it's less than a second in duration - more a brief flicker than it actually all going black for a second - then I have a similar problem with my MacBook Pro (mid 2009 15" model). It's very sporadic, but it seems to be related to the computer being under heavy load (eg running 2 large virtual machines simultaneously) when it's running on the integrated graphics (in energy saver, using 'better battery life' instead of 'better performance'). I've never had it happen on the 'better performance' graphics setting, and I suspect it's something to do with the low-power graphics card.

I do keep meaning to take it to a Genius bar when I get a chance, because it's still under Applecare and it can be annoying (it tends to happen in a flurry of flickers for a minute or two, then nothing for hours on end). However, it's my main work machine and I'm not in a position where I could be without it for a few days, so.... :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is an off chance, but I feel it's worth mentioning: this can happen if you have a hot-corner enabled and set to 'Sleep Display'.  I do, and it'll occasionally happen that I'll accidentally move my mouse into the correct corner and my screen will go dark for a second before mouse movement wakes it up again.

Again, unlikely that this is your issue, but worth checking before you bring it to an Apple store.  Just take a look in System Preferences (under displays or screen savers or something like that).

Comment: Fishtoaster - thank you for your answer, been having the same flickering driving me to expletives at times, just checked my settings searching for 'Hot corners' in display settings, and 'hay presto' all corners set to sleep. Just move your mouse to each of the corners and should go dark until you move the mouse or touch the keyboard. Just set them all to something more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Take the battery out and connect the MacBook to the power adapter. Turn it on and see if the flicker still occurs.

I had this problem and it was due to a battery that was going bad. You can also check the status of your battery in the "Power" section of the System Profiler. If the cycles are high or it says "Check battery" you may need to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It went back to apple and came back with a new Motherboard. The problem persisted. Took it to the genius bar. Had the display and another Motherboard replaced. I can't say that it's totally fixed... but it's happening much less. Like once a day versus several times an hour.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I figured it out. I have no more Black screen issue & flickering since I did below  yesterday:

1. Found advise from a user and Killed process called "warmd", process user: unknown.
   http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/warmd.8.html
2. When my Screen went black sporadically, My ipad was connected and nearby my MacBook , I relocated it further away (I read about interference issues)
3. I right clicked on battery icon and it showed me that Battery needs Service. I fully re-charged and re-booted my Pro and WoohLah, Battery status was back to normal....
4. I switched GPU >> Installed programm called GFXcardstatus (you can Google that)
5. In Applications->Utilities->Terminal
   enter: `sudo pmset -a lidwake 0`   to reverse replace 0 with 1
   enter your computer password...

This sends your laptop to sleep on closing but on opening tap any key to wake. According to advise by other user on the net this has stopped his issue with black screen and lastly I performed it after step 1-4.

Not sure what caused it tho but fiddeling around with above sorted my issue.

---

I posted this comment in the [apple discussions forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3643998).

I hope that helps.

Good luck to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

Ive had similar problem,
The inverter and screen has been replaced by warranty.
Does it happens when you change angle of your lid?